# Why my function addMoedas( ) it's not adding coins to the vault?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, push

```
const cofre = []
```

The vault

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')()
```

`npm` from the node that allows me to use a prompt to collect the inputs.

```
const menuPrincipal = () => {
    console.log('1 - Adicionar Moeda')
    console.log('2 - Remover Moeda')
    console.log('3 - Mostrar todas as moedas no cofre.')
    console.log('4 - Somar quanto dinheiro você tem.')
    const opcao = prompt('Selecione a sua opção: ')

    if (opcao > 0 && opcao < 5) {
        if (Number(opcao) === 1) {
            addMoedas()
        } else if (Number(opcao) === 2) {
            deleteMoeda()
        } else if (Number(opcao) === 3) {
            suasReservas()
        } else if (Number(opcao) === 4) {
            valorTotal()
        } else {
            console.log('Opção inválida!')
        }
    }
}

const addMoedas = () => {
```

This function should read what kind of coin is inputted and its valor, adding it to the vault const cofre.

```
    const moedasAceitas = [5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
```

The coins can't differ from these values.

```
    console.log('1 - Real.')
    console.log('2 - Dólar.')
    console.log('3 - Euro.')
    const currency = prompt('Qual moeda você esta usando?')
    const valor = prompt('Qual o valor da moeda?')

    for (let i of moedasAceitas) {
        if (valor === i) { **>Is this conditional correct?<**
            switch (Number(currency)) {
                case 1:
                    cofre.push(valor)
                    console.log(`Você adicionou RS${valor} centavos ao seu cofre.`)
                    return cofre
                case 2:
                    valor = valor * 5
                    cofre.push(valor)
                    console.log(`Você adicionou $${valor} centavos ao seu cofre.`)
                    return cofre
                case 3:
                    valor = valor * 6
                    cofre.push(valor)
                    console.log(`Você adicionou ξ${valor} centavos ao seu cofre.`)
                    return cofre
                default:
                    console.log('Moeda inválida!')
            }
        }
        menuPrincipal()
```

It should call the menu after the operation.

```
    }
    return cofre
}
```

Function to delete a coin from the vault.

```
const deleteMoeda = () => {
    const apagar = prompt('Qual moeda deseja apagar? ')
    for (let j of cofre) {
        delete apagar[j]
    }
    console.log(cofre)
    menuPrincipal()
    return cofre
}

const suasReservas = () => {
    console.log(cofre)
    menuPrincipal()
}
```

Function to show how much money you gathered in your vault.

```
const valorTotal = () => {
    const total = cofre.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    console.log(total)
    menuPrincipal()
}

menuPrincipal()
```

Comment: `return cofre` in the `switch/case` ends the function, so you never call `menuPrincipal()`

Comment: Don't use a recursive call to go back to the main menu. `menuPrincipal()` should have a loop.

Comment: `if (valor === i)` is not correct. `valor` is a string, `i` is a number. But there's no need for the loop and this condition. You should use `if (moedasAceitas.includes(Number(valor)))`

Comment: I recommend converting the inputs to numbers immediately when you set the variables, so you don't have to keep calling `Number()` when you use it. `valor = Number(prompt('Qual o valor da moeda?'))`